# Activerecord query filter after where

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have run a .where query that selects a group of activerecords. Each of these records has a .items association and each associated item has a theme_id. Is there anyway I can filter only those records that have an associated item that has a theme_id of 0 without having to do a .each of the initial array or any kind of explicit looping?

To illustrate it better:

[p_0,...,p_n] is what I get after the .where filter
each of p has an associated array of [i_0,...,i_n]
and each i has a theme_id. I want to get only those p's that has an item that has a theme_id of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your codebase, so this is a stab in the dark, but couldn't you get the same array by reserving the logic a bit?

```
ary = Item.where(theme_id: 0).map {|i| i.association_you_want }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins). E.g.

```
MyRecord.joins(:items).where("items.theme_id" => 0).distinct
```

The [`distinct`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct) is necessary, because a record with two items will otherwise be included twice in the results. That's a quirk of how database joins work.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord `where` takes a "hash syntax" that allows you to specify associations (and associations of those associations).   The interaction between `joins` and `where` is a little interesting, where `joins` wants the table name and `where` takes the association name.   These hash syntax `where` conditions can be nested as deeply as you need.

In my experience, it's better to stay with the hash syntax (if you can) rather than using string conditions.

```
.joins(:items).where(items: {theme_id: 0})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.